# proof of DCT with weak condition(almost everywhere)

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

I have a question about a proof of the dominating convergence theorem, with weak requirements. Before I show the proof from the book, note that in my book you are allowed to integrate functions that are not defined everywhere, but almost everywhere, the make this definition, it may be relevant to know:

[image]

Now comes the part I do not fully understand. The proof deals with both the real and complex case, but I am only interested in the real case(green). I have outlined what I don't udnerstand(red). They say that for each function they can just assume that $|f_n|<g$ everywhere, not almost everywhere:

[image]

Why can they just assume this?I think it follows because if this doesn't hold we may use some kind of trick to replace these functions with functions that are smaller than g everywhere. But I don't fully understand precisely the details and how I am supposed to do this? Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Because for practical purposes null sets are irrelevant. Formally, let $A_n=\{x: |f_n(x)|> g(x)\}$.By assumption $\mu(A_n)=0$ for each $n$.  Now, define $\overline{f_n}(x)=\begin{cases} f_n(x) \ \rm{if}\ x\notin A_n\\
0 \ \rm{otherwise} \end{cases}$. Since $f_n$ and $\overline{f}_n$ are equal almost everywhere their integrals are the same. So the right hand side limit is the same for both sequences. On the other hand, let $\overline{f}(x)=\begin{cases} \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x) \ \rm{if\ the\ limit\ exists}\ \\
0 \ \rm{otherwise} \end{cases}$.

Observe that $\{x:f(x)\ne \overline{ f}(x)\}\subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$, since a countable union of measure zero sets has measure zero it follows that $\overline{f}$ and $f$ are equal almost everywhere. Thus the left hand side integral are also the same.

Comment: Thanks, do we not have to do any more work? I suspected maybe that we had to collect the null-set for the first n=1, the set for the second n=2, and combine all this sets etc.? But we don't need to do this?

Comment: @user119615 You are right. I'll add more details

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but could you please also prove the set containment you claim? "Observe that {...}"

Comment: @user119615 Outside $\bigcup A_n$ $f_n$ and $\overline{f}_n$ agree for all $n$.

Comment: Is this correct? Let $B=\{x|f(x)=\bar{f}(x)\}$. If $x \in (\bigcup A_n)^C$, then $|f_n(g)|\le g(x), \forall n$. So $\bar{f_n}(x)=f_n(x)$, by the construction of $\bar{f_n}$. So $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\bar{f_n}(x)$, or their limit must both fail to exist, and $f(x)=\bar{f_n}(x)=0$. Hence $x \in B$, this gives $ (\bigcup A_n)^C \subseteq B \rightarrow B^C=\{x| f(x) \ne \bar{f(x)}\}\subseteq\bigcup A_n$.

Comment: @user119615 Exactly.